# Unwanted macOS connection requests

Tags: malware, ios, bluetooth

Even though I didn't initiate anything, popups in macOS popped up a few times asking me to allow a connection request from my (?) iPhone which is already paired with my computer. The device name matched the device name of my iPhone.

The dialog asked me to verify displayed number with a number displayed on my iPhone. My iPhone wasn't showing any number or pairing request in progress. Popups spontaneously disappeared and then reappeared quickly with new number.

Is this just a bug or could this be a malware and I should be worried?

[image]

Comment: From the tag I assume the pairing is done via bluetooth? If so, was bluetooth activated on your phone and/or on your Mac? To give a reasonable evaluation we will need more details on what exactly your setup was/is.

Comment: I assumed it was a bluetooth pairing request, but I'm not sure. Bluetooth is activated on both devices. The dialog looks like this:
http://i63.tinypic.com/dre541.jpg

Comment: Does the problem persist when Bluetooth is disabled on your iPhone? (Do **NOT** turn off Bluetooth on your iMac.)

Comment: This doesn't happen often, I will try to turn off the bluetooth next time.